# Show backordered item status after payment?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, backend, backorder, stock-status

When we receive an order containing an out of stock item (that's allowed to be backordered) it nicely shows "Backordered" at 'Item status' in the backend order detail page (e.g. /admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1234/etcetera).

[image: magento item status = backordered]

But only as long as the invoice is not yet created!
When invoice is created, the item status automatically changes to invoiced, see image.

[image: magento item status = invoiced, even though still in backorder]

This seems not logical to me and is definitely unwanted behavior. Even after the invoice has been created, I'd still like/need to know what products are in backorder.

**Any idea how we can keep the message "backordered" on the order overview?**

*PS: When payment is received, the invoice is automatically created. We could change that to manual (so that we can still see backordered items) but that is not really a solution, since it forces us to manually generate invoices that are now being done automatically.*

Comment: `I stumbled across this query and was wondering if you ever found an answer? ` comment  by **Peter Barton**

Comment: Unfortunately not. But what kinda helped as a workaround, was showing a not-in-stock message in the confirmation mail. Both for us and the customer insightful info. Code found at http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/40376/21234